# STM32F1 ADC_DMA and USART_DMA_TX

Tags: stm32

I try to finish the code about: ADC using DMA and then the data transfer through PC by using USART. I want to use USART_DMA to avoid occupying CPU. I use sample frequency rate 1000Hz by using array ADC[] and delay 1ms (delay here mean I use systemtick, you haven't check this point I am sure it work well).

In this code below, have I missed something?

So here my code:

[image]

USART_DMA code:

```
  /* USARTx configured as follow:
    - BaudRate = 115200 baud
    - Word Length = 8 Bits
    - One Stop Bit
    - No parity
    - Hardware flow control disabled (RTS and CTS signals)
    - Receive and transmit enabled
   */

#include "USART.h"
char TxBuffer[16];

    USART_InitTypeDef                       USART_InitStructure;
    DMA_InitTypeDef                         DMA_InitStructure;

void USART_Configuration(unsigned int BaudRate)
{

        /* Characteristic of USART*/
    USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = BaudRate;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
    USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;

    USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;
    USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);   
        /* Enable USART*/
    USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);  
}

void DMA_Configuration(void)
{

DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel2);

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)TxBuffer; // send buffer
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&USART1->DR;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC; // Transmit
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_VeryHigh; 
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel2, &DMA_InitStructure);

DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel2, ENABLE);
USART_DMACmd(USART1, USART_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);  
while (DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC2) == RESET)
{}
}
```

ADC_DMA code:

```
  #include "ADC_DMA.h"
  uint32_t ADCValue[2] = {0};

void ADC_DMA(void){
ADC_InitTypeDef                 ADC_InitStructure;
DMA_InitTypeDef                 DMA_InitStructure;

        /* DMA Configure */ 
    DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel1);
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&ADCValue; // address of array data
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)(&(ADC1->DR));
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;

    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 2;  // kich thuoc mang du lieu tuong ung so phan tu cua ADCValue
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;

    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;
    DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel1, &DMA_InitStructure);
        /* DMA1_Stream0 enable */ 
    DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel1, ENABLE);

        /* ADC Common Init */
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_None;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfChannel = 2; //so kenh ADC chuyen doi
    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);
        /* ADC1 regular channels configuration */ 
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_0, 1, ADC_SampleTime_7Cycles5);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_1, 2, ADC_SampleTime_7Cycles5);

        /* Enable ADC DMA */ 
    ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
        /* Enable ADC1 */
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

        /* Enable ADC1 reset calibration register */  
    ADC_ResetCalibration(ADC1);
        /* Check the end of ADC1 reset calibration register */
    while(ADC_GetResetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
        /* Start ADC1 calibration */
    ADC_StartCalibration(ADC1);
        /* Check the end of ADC1 calibration */
while(ADC_GetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
        /* Start ADC1 Software Conversion */ 
    ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
}
```

Main function:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "ADC_DMA.h"
#include "USART.h"

/* Declare variable*/
__IO uint16_t x,y;
extern uint32_t time=0;
extern uint32_t ADCValue[];
extern char TxBuffer[16];

GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;


void GPIO_Configuration(void);
void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount);

int main()
{
 GPIO_Configuration();
 ADC_DMA();
 RCC_DeInit();
 USART_Configuration(115200);
 SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000); 
 /****************************************
  *SystemFrequency/1000      1ms         *
  *SystemFrequency/100000    10us        *
  *SystemFrequency/1000000   1us         *
  *****************************************/
while(1)        
{
  Delay(1000);      // 100000 = 100ms           
  x = ADCValue[0];
  y = ADCValue[1];  
}   
 sprintf(TxBuffer,"%d@\n%d$\n", x,y);
}       
  }
 void GPIO_Configuration(void)
 {
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

        /* Configure PB0 PB1 in output pushpull mode */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
        /* Configure PA0 in input mode */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);                           

        /* Enable clock DMA1 */
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);
        /* Enable clock ADC1 */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1 | RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

        /* Configure ADC Pin PA0 & PA1 */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AIN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    /* Enable clock for USART1*/

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE); 
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    /* Enable clock DMA1 */
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);

        /* Configure USART Tx as alternate function  */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

        /* Configure USART Rx as alternate function  */
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

 }

void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount)
 {
time = nCount;
while(nCount--);
 }

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
  { 
 /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
 ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

 /* Infinite loop */
 while (1)
 {
 }
 }
#endif
```